# Too many points getting when creating a route in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am working on an android app for accessing user current location and making a route on google map when location changed.

For request updates I am using Fused location provider and set up for location update is like below:

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

With above set up for the location updates, it is not creating the correct route because of 10 second interval. But if I reduce it to the 1 second then it is creating correct route and sending current location to the server for saving.

Problem is, if there is one route which takes 60 minutes to cover, if I set interval 1 second then it will send too much data on the server for saving which will create problem for the database.

So, how can I get lesser number of latitudes and longitudes while interval time is 1 second?

Comment: Does my answer help? or you are looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce points that are closer together by setting the [SmallestDisplacement](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) to a reasonable value, in which case, you will only get meaningful lat/lng update. Doing this should reduce your number of points.

Also you might able to reduce the points by using the [Snap to Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap?hl=en), which takes inputs points and return the possible route that set of points representance. From the returned result, you should able to decode the polyline and get a minimum number of points that representance the path.